# Spring @Autowired confusion (container or session)

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations, autowired

In My app I am using a `User` bean that is Autowired to my service `MyService` and its used as the principle logged in user's info (So the user is not coming as a static bean from an xml but dynamically generated from a logged in user) If there are ten users logged in I will have ten candidates for the `@AutoWired` `User` field. (right?) and I can get any one of them cos AutoWired looks in the Spring container and not session.

tell me if I am wrong on this. and how to actually solve it if possible. But what if my AutoWired field is annotated with `@Scope ("Session")`

Like this :

```
@Component("user")
@Scope("session")
public class User 
{
String userid;
String name;
//getter setters etc
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class MyService
{
    @Autowired
    private User user;

}
```

Is it possible to get some other user's User bean when I call my `MyService` Component. Cos `MyService` is only `@Component` even though the `User` is `@Scope(session)`.

Basically, (If I am wrong in my assumption) I think that when you `@Autowire` a field, its looks into the container as whole and the container is not divided into subcontainers per session.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you annotate `User` with `@Scope("session")` and then `@Autowire` that into another non-scoped component, Spring will generate a proxy which sits between `MyService` and `User`. This proxy will locate the `User` from the current session, and will delegate any calls from `MyService` to the proxy to the session-scoped `User`.

So it's perfectly safe, the `MyService` component will only have access to the `User` from the current session.

If the proxying didn't happen, then the container would fail to start, since you can't directly inject a session-scoped bean into singleton-scoped bean.

Comment: So its not possible that when I do a ` SpringUtils.getContext(req).getBean("myservice")`, I will get some other user bean that is not in the current session.

Comment: @sarmahdi: That's correct. The current user's session is a thread-local variable maintained by Spring.

Comment: So its not possible that when I do a ` SpringUtils.getContext(req).getBean("myservice")`, I will get some other user bean that is not in the current session.
Actually I got this issue that I loaded a page and I got some other users details. So i was thinking that it might be cos even though the User is sessions scoped the service is not and non scoped are by default singelton.

Comment: @sarmahdi: No, this would not have been the cause - something else is going on.

Comment: thanks.  So when you actually Do a @Scope(Session) it gets bind with a session which is a thread local variable...

Comment: Thanks... Its an Ahan! moment for me.. :) appreciate it

Comment: Oh I have a complex scenario for this one again (Do I need to ask it as another question) If MyService which is just a atComponent calls another MySecondService which is also only atComponent and MySecondService has an atAutoWired User user; Will that also get the session scoped User for that user's thread local.

Comment: never mind, component is a component doesnt matter what stage of the execution it is.

Comment: If I annotate MyService with atScope("Singleton"), Will that be a problem in this case. I am asking cos when you dont annotate its by default singleton and some one told me that you need to make it atScope("prototype"). I kinda disagree with him and thats why I am asking you cos I think the problem should be else where it should not have any scope issues as long as my User is bind to session scope.

Answer (score 15):

Spring would not automatically create a proxy. You need to change your scope annotation to the following

```
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

This would ensure that when the session bean is getting autowired in a singleton class, a proxy is created around the bean which would be responsible to get the bean from the session.